# Adding a button to the topbar that won't collapse on small screens

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm building an app using foundation 5. I'm using foundation's topbar, which collapses to the (menu) hamburger button on small screens.

I want to add a button, that will be visible next to that button only on small displays.

I've tried adding the button outside of the top-bar-section, but that places the button outside of the entire topbar. I also tried putting it inside the title area but than it doesn't even render.

I know I can use show-for-small-only class to display the button only on small devices, but what I don't know is how force it to stay presented when the topbar collapses on small displays.

Comment: min and max width may help , as might media queries

Comment: do you have a link to a sample page?